# How to run additional actions after binding completes in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am trying to figure out how to run an action after binding completes

For example

```
<input type="text" @bind="@Model.Value" />

<h2>@Value2</h2>

@code
{

void SetNewValue()
{
    Value2 = $"New value {this.Model.Value} added on {DateTime.Now}";
}

string Value2 {get;set;}

}
```

This is just a simple example. I cannot use onchange since it cannot be used with bind. I tried to use onkeyup but that is executed before binding completes. Blazor doesnt have an option to handle focus lost, so I really dont know how to get this done.

Comment: Can't you just use onChange instead of binding? If onchange is not an option, you can use oninput.

Comment: Bind the input to value2 and use the setter of value2 to set model.Value

Comment: @ŠtefanBartoš how would you use onchange instead of binding? Please provide me with an example

Comment: @MisterMagoo I was leaning towards that solution ,didnt try it yet. Will try it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @page "/"

<input type="text" value="@model.Value" @onchange="@((args) => { model.Value = 
 args.Value.ToString(); SetNewValue(); })" />

<h2>@Value2</h2>

@code
{

private Model model = new Model();

void SetNewValue()
{
    Value2 = $"New value {this.model.Value} added on {DateTime.Now}";
}

string Value2 { get; set; }



public class Model
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since **.Net 7** do you have [Blazor data binding get/set/after modifiers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-7/#blazor-data-binding-get-set-after-modifiers):

> In .NET 7 you can now easily run async logic after a binding event has completed using the new @bind:after modifier:

```
<input @bind="searchText" @bind:after="PerformSearch" />

@code {
    string searchText;

    async Task PerformSearch()
    {
        // ... do something asynchronously with 'searchText' ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, there are known issues with earliest .NET 7 runtime which will be fixed in upcoming release. See issue mentioned here: 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44957

Comment: As mentioned in the article, you can obtain a nightly build of .NET 7 runtime which fixes the bug here:
https://github.com/dotnet/installer#table
Also, you will need a Nuget.config with suggested content to make it work. 
This will be fixed in upcoming .NET 7 release.

Comment: Is @bind-event="oninput" also necessary in your example to see changes after key stroke ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with onchange, but it fires after lost focus. If you want to call function while letter change, you can use oninput.

```
<input @oninput="OnValueChanged" value="@Value" />

Value: <div>@Value</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value.ToString();

        return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use oninput instead of onchange. Can you tell the difference?

Comment: it fires events while you typing(each letter) where onchange fires after it loses focus

Comment: This does not simulate exact behavior as 2-way binding. Oninput fires after letter change where onchage or 2-way binding after it loses focus.Therefore, enet answer is right.